# Using trace to call proc when value in variable changes TCL

Tags: tcl, trace, proc

I have a file storing some data:

```
miscellaneous data1
```

The file would occasionally be opened and the data would be changed.

```
356
miscellaneous data2
```

data in the file would be stored into a variable $fileData every 10 seconds

**Data storing procedure**

```
proc storeData {} {
 global fileData
 if {[info exists fileData]} {
  set fileData ""
 }
 set fp [open file1.txt r]
 while {[gets $fp data] > -1} {
  lappend fileData $data\n
 }
 close $fp
}
```

**Procedure to run storeData every 10 seconds**

```
proc every {ms body} {
 if 1 $body
 after $ms [list after idle [info level 0]]
}
every 10000 {storeData}
```

**Procedure to call when value in fileData is changed**

```
proc valueChanged {} {
 puts "Value in fileData has changed."
}
```

How do I apply the trace command such that if the value in fileData is different from the last iteration of the script, it will call the proc valueChanged? 
So far i have tried adding the trace command

```
trace add variable fileData write "valueChanged"
```

after calling

```
every 10000 {storeData}
```

but it is just printing out the message even if the value is unchanged.

Comment: Whenever the variable is written this will be called. i.e. whenever you use `set` command to set a value to the traced variable, this will be called.

Comment: I see, should i use the read operation instead?

Comment: Nope, still that will be printed whenever it is being read. For example, `puts $fileData` will cause trace to trigger as it involves the read operation. Whatever you are interested in terms of checking the content is same or different, you have to manually check the same. You may not even need `trace` at all.

Comment: Straightaway you can check it while reading the file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are changing the variable `fileData` independently of changes in the file content everytime you call `storeData`. What's more, you're changing the variable several times for each call: once when you reset it, and once for every line that you `lappend` to it. Revised `storeData` that brings the number of changes down to one per call:

```
proc storeData {} {
    global fileData
    set temp {}
    set fp [open file1.txt r]
    while {[gets $fp data] > -1} {
        lappend temp $data\n
    }
    set fileData $temp
    close $fp
}
```

The `valueChanged` command needs to look for actual differences and not just accept writes as indicative of changes. Another global variable can hold the latest known content of `fileData`

```
proc valueChanged args {
    global storedValue fileData
    if {![info exists storedValue]} {
        set storedValue $fileData
    } elseif {$storedValue ne $fileData} {
        puts "Value in fileData has changed."
        set storedValue $fileData
    } else {
        puts "Value in fileData is the same."
    }
}
```

The `valueChanged` procedure needs to be defined like this:

```
proc valueChanged args {
    ...
}
```

because it will be called with three arguments (variable name, member name, and operation). Even if you don't use these arguments you need to ensure that the procedure can receive them, otherwise the call will fail.

Documentation: [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm), [global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm), [info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
set fileData {}
proc storeData {} {
    global fileData
    set fp [open file1.txt r]
    set localData {}
    while {[gets $fp data] > -1} {
        lappend localData $data\n
    }
    if {$localData ne $fileData} {
        # Resetting the global 'fileData' content
        set fileData $localData
        puts "content changed"
    }
    close $fp
}
```